# characteristics in a simple region

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For the system of equations describing a compressible fluid

$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}  + u \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + \rho \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}  + \frac{c^2}{\rho} \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x} + u \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 0$

the characteristic curves, $C_{\pm}$, are determined from $\frac{d x}{d t} = u \pm c$. It can be shown that along such curves, the Riemann invariants, $\Gamma_{\pm} = u \pm \frac{2c}{\gamma-1}$ are constant. A simple region is defined when one of the $\Gamma$'s, say $\Gamma_-$ is not only constant on a particular $C_-$ but through out some region. In particular $\Gamma_-$ is also constant on $C_+$.

My question is, why does this imply that $u + c$ is constant on each $C_+$ (so that the $C_+$ form a set of parallel lines)? As far as I can tell, since $\Gamma_-$ is constant through the region doesn't this mean $\Gamma_- = u - \frac{2c}{\gamma-1} = k$, with $k$ a constant and for a given $C_+$ curve we have $\Gamma_+ = u + \frac{2c}{\gamma-1} = l(C_+)$, where the "constant" $l(C_+)$ varies for different $C_+$ characteristic curves. Doesn't this give for a particular $C+$ curve $u - \frac{2c}{\gamma-1} = u + \frac{2c}{\gamma-1}$, *i.e.* $c = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have figured the answer. May be of interest to others so writing as an answer:

Along a given $C_+$ curve, $\Gamma_+ = u + \frac{2c}{\gamma -1} = l(C_+)$ (where the constant depends on the particular curve $C_+$ being considered). For a simple region $S$,  $\Gamma_- = u - \frac{2c}{\gamma -1} = k$ for all $C_-$ curves and so is constant through out $S$. So on a given $C_+$ curve have  $u + \frac{2c}{\gamma -1} = l(C_+)$ and $u - \frac{2c}{\gamma -1} = k$. These can easily be solved to yield on the given $C_+$ curve that $u + c = (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\gamma-1}{4})l(C_+) + (\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\gamma-1}{4})k$. But the the $C_+$ characteristics are determined from solving $\frac{dx}{dt} = u + c$ so that the $C_+$ characteristics are straight lines.